# Android NDK builds well, gradle cant find header

Tags: boost, gradle, android-ndk, header

I have an android problem. I am using ndk with makefiles and android studio with gradle.

My app should use boost and a premade library too, called "kodo".
I made makefiles like this: 
Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
# build jni
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := **/*.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

And I have some code, that uses these:

```
#include <kodo/object/file_encoder.hpp>
#include <kodo/rlnc/full_rlnc_codes.hpp>

#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

The first words are red, stating cannot find 'kodo' and cannot find 'boost'.
NDK-build runs well (seemingly) having no errors.
Still the build fails, when trying to be put together in an app.

If you could help, I would be so happy.
Thanks,
Krisz.

Comment: the kodo and boost folders are under the jni folder